# Reformatting XML document in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have an XML document that is not formatted well, it will have many elements on one line for example:

```
<ModelRefs><ParentViewName>schematic</ParentViewName><ParentCellName>NCH_HS1_MV5</ParentCellName><InstanceName>DSDP</InstanceName><InstanceCellName>DIODE2MI_perim_shrink</InstanceCellName><InstanceLibName>tiRefLib</InstanceLibName></ModelRefs>
```

I would like to re-format it -- I tried reading it in/parsing with XML::LibXML lib, but then regardless of which format option I use in (1, 2, or 3 etc)
 $xmldoc->toFile($file, 2);

I still don't get it 'normalized' and indented properly... can you help me how to do it? (I don't have Twig on my machine)...

Comment: For documents *with* blanks, you need `no_blanks => 1`, but for the one you gave, it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I know you say you don't have `XML::Twig` available, but it really is good for this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' ) -> parse ( \*DATA ) -> print;


__DATA__

<ModelRefs><ParentViewName>schematic</ParentViewName><ParentCellName>NCH_HS1_MV5</ParentCellName><InstanceName>DSDP</InstanceName><InstanceCellName>DIODE2MI_perim_shrink</InstanceCellName><InstanceLibName>tiRefLib</InstanceLibName></ModelRefs>
```